# ASP.net webform design

Tags: asp.net, design-patterns, webforms

I can't figure out a good design for this.

I have an edit product page.  It allows you to change basic product details, product name etc.

Then I have a function to upload images of the product.

I also have a small page for adding different prices based on date ranges for the product.

What I can't figure out, is how to have these on the same page so as not to have a billion tiny pointless pages when I would much rather have them all on one page.

ASP.net webforms seems to only allow 1 form per page!

Comment: maybe it is a http://ui.stackexchange.com/ question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need more than one form. You just hook up a button_click event for the different buttons on the page, such that only the relevant code is executed when the user clicks one of the buttons.

Answer (score 3):

ASP.NET Webforms allows only one form per page, but you can create interesting UIs without hitch.

Here is an Open Source Codeplex Project [ShoppingCart.NET](http://shoppingcartnet.codeplex.com/), download it and check the Product Catalog CMS section. That will help you to learn the trick...

All the best